# Algebraic Speed Distance And Time Question GCSE

Tags: classical-mechanics

Question:
[image: Question:]

What I did:

$x$ = miles   $\frac{x}{60mph}$ and $\frac{x}{45mph}$

and so $x = 60t$ and $x = 45t$

I don't know what to do from here to work out time.

Thankyou, any help is appreciated!

Comment: The times of the journeys are different for outward and return. Thus you must use an index for the times. $t_1=\frac{x}{60}$ for $\color{cyan}a$ and $t_2=\frac{x}{45}$ for $\color{cyan}b$. That´s all for $\color{cyan}a$ and $\color{cyan}b$. Can you continue with $\color{cyan}c$?

Comment: $\frac{x}{60}$ + $\frac{x}{40}$ = 420  (420 seconds)

Comment: Basically you´re right. But on the RHS you have hours. Thus the equation is  $\frac{x}{60}+\frac{x}{45}=7$

Comment: @xx_Gcsemathstudent_xx:  $420$ is minutes, not seconds.  You can work the whole problem in hours.

Comment: Oh yes sorry thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should say $\frac x{60mph}$ is the outward time and $\frac x{45mph}$ is the return time.  Just writing the two fractions down leaves it unclear what they mean and lead to your assumption that the two times are the same.

Then it is clear that the total time is $7hours=\frac x{60mph}+\frac x{45mph}$  Now multiply by something to clear the fractions, like $180$ because it is the least common multiple of $45$ and $60$, giving $$7\cdot 180=3x+4x\\180=x$$